# How to pop the last positional argument of a bash function or script?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I often need to pop the last positional argument of a bash function or script.

By "pop" I mean: "remove it from the list of positional arguments, and (optionally) assign it to a variable."

Given how frequently I need this operation, I am a bit surprised that best I have found is what is illustrated by the example below:

```
foo () {
    local argv=( "$@" )
    local last=${argv[$(( ${#argv[@]} - 1 ))]}
    argv=( ${argv[@]:0:$(( ${#argv[@]} - 1 ))} )
    echo "last: $last"
    echo "rest: ${argv[@]}"
}
```

In other words, an epic production featuring a cast of thousands...

Is there anything simpler, easier to read?

Comment: I find it interesting that you need to perform a remove-last operation that often. The reason there is a separate `shift` keyword is that removing the _first_ element from the list of positional parameters is a common thing to want to do. Care to say something about your use cases?

Comment: FYI all the `$(( ))` could be removed without impact, but Quasímodo has the actual answer.

Comment: Don't write your scripts and functions to need popping off the last positional parameter, and your life will be much easier, and your scripts especially will conform better to unix conventions, not to mention simpler by avoiding the shell's excessively ugly syntax around arrays. If you provide a more concrete example, I'd be happy to give a more detailed response.

Comment: @DaleHagglund: I obviously don't know what kjo's use-case is, but both `mv` and `cp` have a "special" last parameter, so it's conceivable that kjo's use-case conforms to Unix conventions as well.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can access the last element with `${argv[-1]}` (bash 4.2 or above) and remove it from the array with the `unset` builtin (bash 4.3 or above):

```
last=${argv[-1]}
unset 'argv[-1]'
```

The quotes around `argv[-1]` are required as `[...]` is a glob operator, so `argv[-1]` unquoted could expand to `argv-` and/or `argv1` if those files existed in the current directory (or to nothing or cause an error if they didn't with `nullglob`/`failglob` enabled).

Answer (score 15):

How about this:

```
foo () {
    local last="${!#}"
    local argv=("${@:1:$#-1}")
    echo "last: $last"
    echo "rest: ${argv[@]}"
}
```

Comment: That's interesting, I've never seen `${!#}` used before, any idea where it's officially documented?  Only a very small number of search results here: http://symbolhound.com/?q=%24%7B%21%23%7D. Nice answer BTW.

Comment: `!` is for dereferencing and `#` is the number of arguments, so `!#` dereferences the last argument.

Answer (score 6):

You can simplify a little to make it easier on the eye, but the fundamental method is unchanged (this might be useful if you have a Bash version which doesn't support [Quasímodo's offering](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/611717/40482)):

```
foo () {
    local argv=( "$@" )
    local last="${argv[$# - 1]}"
    argv=( "${argv[@]:0:$# - 1}" )
    echo "last: $last"
    echo "rest: ${argv[@]}"
}
```

I concede that it's a bit cheeky use `$#` in this way, but it has the same value as `${#argv[@]}` *in this specific example* and is more concise in code.

Answer (score 3):

For the record, in case switching to `zsh` is an option, in `zsh`, the array of positional parameters **is** the `$argv` array (zsh arrays are true arrays, and with indices starting at one like the positional parameters), so, there, it's just:

```
foo () {
    local last=$argv[-1]
    argv[-1]=()
    print -rC1 "last: $last" rest: ' - '$^argv
}
```

Though you could also do:

```
foo () {
    print -rC1 "last: $argv[-1]" rest: ' - '$^argv[1,-2]
}
```

And if the end goal is to loop over the positional parameters in reverse order:

```
for arg in "${(Oa)@}"; do
  something with "$arg"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

For a simpler equivalent to [bxm’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/611718), use `set`:

```bsh
pop() {
  last="${!#}"  # see man bash, search for "indirect expansion"
  set -- "${@:1:$#-1}"

  printf 'not last: %s\n' "$@"
  printf 'last: %s\n' "${last}"
}

pop 1 2 3 4
# prints:
# not last: 1
# not last: 2
# not last: 3
# last: 4
```

Here, `${!#}` is an indirect parameter expansion (search for “indirect
expansion” in `man bash`), and `set -- ARGS...` sets the new values of
the arguments (`$1`, etc.) to the given args.

Notably, `${!#}` and the array slicing are bashisms, but `set --` is
portable to any POSIX shell.

Comment: That's essentially the same as [Gordon's answer](/a/611739), except it modifies the positional parameters in place instead of an `$argv` copy. Note  that `${var:start:length}` is from ksh93 initially, not bash (and `zsh` had `$var[first,last]` long before ksh93 existed or bash had arrays).

Comment: Right, yep. Since the OP asked to “remove it from the list of positional arguments”, I thought that this seemed appropriate.

Comment: This works on bash5. The accepted answer doesn't. Thank you!